# Connect to TCP socket listener with a WebSocket server

Tags: sockets, networking, heroku, tcp, websocket

I have a application that has a TCP socket listener that I need to broadcast from a server-side application to. I do not control this TCP listener and can't make any changes to it. Is there any way to broadcast to that listener with WebSockets instead of TCP? I know that WebSockets are an Application Level networking tool that implements a HTTP handshake, among other things, over a TCP connection. Is there any way to strip that extra stuff off?

I ask because the application will be running on Heroku, which does not support TCP connections.

I have tried writing a little talker and listener application and the listener receives a HTTP header and seemingly nothing else when I try to broadcast to it, which is expected.

Comment: You should not use broadcast unless you have a need to interrupt every host on a LAN, and broadcast is done with UDP, not TCP. I think you know the IP address of the listener, so you should use unicast. Also, an application that uses HTTP _is_ using TCP since HTTP runs on top of TCP.

Comment: Sorry, my terminology must be wrong. I though broadcast just meant "send a message to". And to be more explicit, Heroku does not support me making connections directly over TCP, only over Application Layer protocols.

Comment: Broadcast sends to every host on a LAN. Multicast sends to all the hosts listening to a specific multicast group. Unicast sends to a single host. Anycast sends to a single host among several that use the same address.

Comment: I appreciate the info. Is there any solution to my issue that I'm having that you know of?

Comment: It sounds like you would need a Websocket <=> Socket proxy.... I'm sure there are Node.js packages for that (even though it probably isn't the best platform to write a proxy server)... Your client will connect to the Websocket proxy and the proxy will connect to the regular TCP socket server and  bridge the connection.